# Urn extraction with replacement and order of the extraction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose we have an urn with 5 balls: 3 green and 2 red. What is the probability of extracting green-red-green (in this order, putting back each ball after the extraction)? Is it different or the same as the probability of extracting 2 green and 1 red (again, putting the ball back in after each extraction)?

I would compute one of these two probabilities as just $3/5\times 3/5 \times 2/5$, but I'm not sure which.

Comment: $\frac 35 \cdot \frac 25 \cdot \frac 35$ is the probability of drawing in the order $GRG$. If any two of the three draws can be green, then it is ${3 \choose 2} \cdot \frac 35 \cdot \frac 25 \cdot \frac 35$

Comment: @MathLover Thanks. Where does the second formula come from?

Comment: It includes GRG, GGR and RGG.

Comment: @BruceET But what is the general formula?

Comment: you are basically adding probability of drawing $RGG, GRG$ and $GGR$. given that you are drawing with replacement, it is binomial distribution. please refer to this wiki page which describes different types of urn problems and links to relevant pages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem

Comment: Two situations and two formulas have been discussed. @MathLover first comment has given you both.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may not understand the combinatorial
approaches. Maybe a simulation (in R) will help:

Let Green=1 and Red = 2. Let `urn=c(1,1,1,2,2)`. Use the `sample` procedure in R to sample three balls from the urn with
replacement, and note whether the sequence was
exactly `121`

```
samp = sample(urn,3,rep=T); samp
[1] 1 2 1
samp==c(1,2,1)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
sum(samp==c(1,2,1)) == 3
[1] TRUE   # YES, we got '121'

samp = sample(urn,3,rep=T); samp
[1] 2 1 2
samp==c(1,2,1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
sum(samp==c(1,2,1)) == 3
[1] FALSE # NO, not `121`
```

Iterate a million times. The fraction of `TRUE`s is almost exactly $18/125,$ as in the first formula.

```
set.seed(2022)
# Denote G = 1; R = 2
urn = c(1,1,1,2,2)
grg = replicate(10^6, 
       sum(sample(urn,3,rep=T)==c(1,2,1))==3)
mean(grg)
[1] 0.14406
18/125
[1] 0.144
```

If we iterate again, noting just whether we got
two green balls (regardless of order), we get
almost exactly $18/125$ as in the the second formula.

```
two.g = replicate(10^6, 
        sum(sample(urn,3,rep=T)==1))
mean(two.g==2)
[1] 0.432297
54/125
[1] 0.432
```

Alternatively, if you know about binomial distributions, the second formula gives a
binomial probability.

Dpecifically, if $G$ is the number of green balls in $n=3$
draws with replacement from an urn with $p = 3/5$ green balls, then $G \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n,p).$
And by the binomial PDF the answer is the same.

```
dbinom(2, 3, 3/5)
[1] 0.432
```